# FCM messages are not delivered when the device is started and it has a password

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-reboot

On android, the messages do not arrive after I restart my device and have a password, if he has no password he receives the message

I would like to understand this situation, whether it is for security or really is a sdk failure